# Why is \t not being applied to this string?

Tags: swift

Almost trivial to ask, but i'm confused and curious. Why is the "\t" special character not applying a tab for:

[image: image1]

It looks like the "\t" character only applied a single space rather than a tab. However if I move the "\t" character over, it applies it like so

[image: image2]

Any ideas?

Comment: In most text editors tabs are defined at fixed positions rather than a of a fixed width. So in the first string the distance of the second "l" to the next tab position is just one space.

Comment: "not applying a tab"  It does.

Comment: @vadian how do we know where this fixed position will be? There doesn't seem to be a pattern .

Comment: It's more likely to be related to your terminal software.

Answer (score 2):

'Tabs' are actually applied. Tabs' width is usually determined by your terminal. In StackOverflow's (web-fronted) case, it's 4 characters wide. Output goes like this.

```
    b
a   b
aa  b
aaa b
aaaa    b
aaaaa   b
aaaaaa  b
aaaaaaa b
aaaaaaaa    b
aaaaaaaaa   b
aaaaaaaaaa  b
aaaaaaaaaaa b
aaaaaaaaaaaa    b
aaaaaaaaaaaaa   b
aaaaaaaaaaaaaa  b
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b
```

Not really an answer but explains the problem well.